# Button to update MySQL column not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

I want to update my database with an SQL statement once someone clicks a button on the website. I've tried something, no success. Can you guys help me ? Here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/D0S83Jgh
Don't know if I made this question correctly, I'm new here.

Comment: Is that in a form? You are using prepared statements incorrectly, `$id` should be a placeholder.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php (assuming a PDO connection) --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and apply that to your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am handling errors in pdoconnect.php, so i don't know if it's required here.

Comment: Where does `$row` come from

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'll edit the question with the full code. Gimme a few secs.

Comment: too many unknowns, which is why I gave you those links. The fact that we don't know how those $_REQUESTs are being populated, is unclear. Again, check for errors.

Comment: probably getting undefined index notices in the background. name attributes work with forms, I don't see one. Unless you're using JS/Ajax but you're not showing/telling us.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: I dont see a `<form......>` tag anywhere. Is there one ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly too many comments have been left about that and checking for errors. I'm out.

Comment: Is there more than one ROW returned in your WHILE LOOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prepared statement is wrong.

The code I use with pdo to do a query is this:

```
$sqlUpd = $upd->prepare("UPDATE league_signups SET approved='1' WHERE id = :id");
$q->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
```

Should work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for editing that part, but the button still doesn't work :/ Like it's not functioning.

Comment: error_reporting(-1);

Add this to the top of your page inside the php. Let me know the error you're getting.

Comment: ^ that, is what I told them already, as per [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515177/button-to-update-mysql-column-not-working#comment56771256_34515177) but it seems like they're already "checking" for errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I know, but sometimes it's easier and faster just to give them a code to work with :).

Comment: I've added the error_reporting(-1) but still nothing. I think the problem is that PHP doesn't even get that button click.

Comment: @iDentity: Don't forget to put a ; after the (-1) or it won't work :).

Comment: @ChrisG I know, but still, nothing. Usually when there is an error i would catch it while the page is loading, but nothing's happening, no errors.

Comment: `error_reporting(-1)` will only log and not "display". If they don't know how to check logs, or don't have access to logs, then they need to "display". If  they're not getting any, then the OP's using JS/Ajax and isn't checking their console. I've done what I could to help here.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I use it all the time and it does display errors.

Comment: @ChrisG sure, "you", but we don't know if the OP's system is setup the same way. Best bet: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` I think the OP's not showing us everything, or has failed to use form tags, which name attributes require a form, or at least a GET method in an href, or jQuery/Ajax. Again, too many unknowns and I've already stated that and others about the possible missing `<form>` tag with GET/POST. I think you may have fallen into a rabbit hole here. I sincerely wish the best for all.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9jx6hv
And yes, `error_repoting(-1);` is in <?php tag on the top of the page.
And yes, the php.ini on XAMPP: http://prntscr.com/9jx7qy

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Hmm, you might be right about that. Good thing there is more then only me here hahahha :D

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);` not `error_repoting(-1);` if that's what you're really using @iDentity

Comment: @iDentity: Where is that error coming from with mData? Might be the cause.

Comment: @iDentity `mData`? where's that coming from? See, I knew it. We're all chasing a rabbit down an endless hole. You need to debug here. That's your job, not ours and you failed to show us relevant code. Although you state as "being new" here, you seem to know how *Stack rolls*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- mistyped in comments, it's correct in code. mData is coming from Datatables.js

Comment: that `mData` seems to be JS related. This question should be edited to show FULL code. @iDentity unless you're trolling us which I hope you're not.

Comment: @iDentity: Would it be possible to have a link to the webpage you are getting this problem from. We might be able to get more out of that. Or make a JSFiddle with all your html code to start off with. That way we can make sure your html is fine/

Comment: mData error is there just because of the table formation problems, nothing that could break the button. I'll give you guys the whole page in a few minutes, since I know it's hard to help like this.

Comment: @ChrisG There's the html/php. If .js is needed i'll upload them all somewhere.

Comment: @iDentity: You should wrap your table into a form. Only then will your button work.

Comment: @ChrisG That was the answer for the button. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to check this as your answer so people know it's answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Get this code out of the main loop: while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {}

```
<?php
include('pdoconnect.php');
$id = isset($row['id'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['approve']))
{
    $sqlUpd = "UPDATE league_signups SET approved='1' WHERE id=$id";
    $q = $upd->prepare($sqlUpd);
    $q->execute();
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['unapprove']))
{
    $sqlUpd = "UPDATE league_signups SET approved='0' WHERE id=$id";
    $q = $upd->prepare($sqlUpd);
    $q->execute();
}
?>
```

Put this code after the loop ending or the beginning of your code...

The data you want to update comes from the checkbox am I right? then you may want to make a loop to update all the values selected with checkbox to the corresponding action 'approve' or 'unapproved'

remove include('pdoconnect.php'); its utterly unnecessary if you are including this file from the beginning already

```
<?php

// checkbox[] it's an array...
$UpdateIDs = (isset($_REQUEST['checkbox'])) ? $_REQUEST['checkbox'] : [];
// check if $_REQUEST['approve'] is set else check if $_REQUEST['unapprove'] is set else set $approve to null;
$approved = (isset($_REQUEST['approve']) ? 
     $_REQUEST['approve'] : 
     (isset($_REQUEST['unapprove'])) ? $_REQUEST['unapprove'] : null;

if(!is_null($approved))
{
     try {
         foreach($UpdateIDs as $ID)
         {
             $stmt = $upd->prepare("UPDATE league_signups SET approved=:approved WHERE id=:id");
             $stmt->execute([
                 ':approved' => $approved,
                 ':id' => $ID
             ]);
         }
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
         echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\league_panel\admin\index.php on line 315     


That's this line:    


`(isset($_REQUEST['unapprove'])) ? $_REQUEST['unapprove'] : null;`

Comment: Sorry yeah i think you right i have missed to enclose that line in parenthesis. did it work at the end?

Comment: I've marked Chris' answer as question answer for button not working, but I haven't resolved the issue completely. I've tried your code and added single Approve/Un-Approve buttons to the page, but it doesn't update data in MySQL.

Comment: You want to select specific rows and update all selected at once or want it to update one by one using approve/unapprove button for each row?

Comment: Oh nevermind in your main post says one by one... gimme a sec im fixing it

Comment: Well, i'm up for any solution, checkboxes or one by one doesn't matter.

Comment: Nope. I think i'm gonna rewrite everything :@

Comment: did you add the file to 'action' attribute at form tag? the method is post so try change $_REQUEST to $_POST x.x

Comment: this: <input type="hidden" name="approve" value="1"> should be set to value='0' and the other well set to 1 now im noticing it

Comment: Works now. Thanks so much man! Dunno if i can set the answer checkmark thing multiple times here, if I can comment again so I can do it. Again, thanks :)

Comment: If you need any other help you can contact me through github glad to help people about PHP